# \printglossary is not printing anything in Overleaf

Tags: glossaries, overleaf

I made this simple code to try to print a glossary, but it doesn't works. The strange things is that the code is just like the one on the Overleaf website:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{glossario.tex}

\begin{document}

\section{Glossario}
\parindent=0em

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

And this is my glossario.tex file:

```
    \newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
    name=formula,
    description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
```

Comment: Only the items that are used in the document are shown. If you don't use any items then nothing is shown. If you add, for example, `\gls{gcd}` after `\begin{document}` it should work. Maybe you need to clear the cache in Overleaf (there should be a button somewhere) to make it work.

Comment: The following link describes how to clear the cache on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Answer (score 3):

- Do not place your main tex file in a **folder**. Make sure your project is on root directory.
- [Clear the cache](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) like mentioned by @craymichael
- Use your Glossary or Acronym at least on time: `\gls{latex}`, `\acrshort{gcd}`, `\acrlong{gcd}`, etc.

Comment: "main tex file not in a folder" did it for me. This took me 2 days

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, in general, assuming a clean compile, add `\glsaddall` before `\printglossary`. This adds all glossary entries and all should be printed.

If this does not resolve the issue in Overleaf, try clearing the cache by clicking the **Logs and output files** button next to **Recompile** and then click the trash can. See instructions [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache).