# overleaf not printing glossaries

Tags: glossaries, overleaf

I have a tex document which renders glossaries just fine when compiled locally. However, when using overleaf the entries defined as `\newacronym` are linked, but the summary of the glossary entries is not output even though `\printGlossaries` is called.

Are there some hidden settings in the overleaf compiler to enable glossaries?

### edit

as requested:

1. The overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/3442153234jktjqgtdjkmw
2. the contents directly below as well

The document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{isp}{ISP}{internet service provider}

\begin{document}
A dummy glossary not showing up \gls{isp}.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Overleaf uses `latexmk` to automatically compile your document. In my very limited experience with glossary-related matters `latexmk` does not always run all required tools (not sure if that is me or `latexmk`'s configurations). If you document needs many `makeglossaries`/... calls, you may have to set up some custom rules in a `latexmkrc` file: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_use_latexmkrc_with_Overleaf:_examples_and_techniques

Comment: Interesting. I just found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481399/printglossary-is-not-printing-anything-in-overleaf however, their solution does not work for me.

Comment: @moewe: I am not really familiar with `latexmk`, as I use TexPad locally. Which commans would be required to force overleaf to run the make clossaries twice?

Comment: Don't know: the required commands will depend on your document setup. Since I have pretty much no experience with glossaries I can't guess what would be needed from only the two commands you mention. I may be able to find out what is required if you post a minimal example, but don't count on it.

Comment: Sure: https://www.overleaf.com/3442153234jktjqgtdjkmw is a dummy project on overleaf with a dummy acronym where the glossary is not showing up

Comment: Any chance you can post the code here? Not everyone has an Overleaf account and external links may become stale. In principle it should be possible to minimise code examples that they comfortably fit the character limit for questions here.

Comment: Done - added the example code here. But still, in the end, it should run on overleaf ;)

Comment: Sure, but as I said: Overleaf uses `latexmk`, so all test can be performed locally. Is it important that you use `IEEEtran` or would it be possible to minimise the example further down to https://gist.github.com/moewew/378829869d90fcf81e1eafc72c94b69a?

Comment: No this is fine. Even with the GIST you linked I can reproduce the issue in overleaf. (and the overleaf link points now to the updated more minimalistic example).

Comment: It would be *very* useful in that case to post the minimised example as it avoids any distractions with the document class and all the stuff it comes with

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a look at the example and as suspected, it would ideally be compiled with `makeglossaries`, but `latexmk` does not do that automatically. I will look into `latexmkcr` files. But note that in the example `\printglossary` will never produce any output, since you only define acronyms the command to print them is `\printacronyms`. (This is not the issue in your actual document, since there the local compilation works, but the MWE should ideally be a minimal example of what your local document looks like.)

Comment: Adding `\printacronyms` solves the issue on overleaf for the minimal example! However, not for my IEEE based real document.

Comment: Even for the longer minimalistic example `\printacronyms` works. But not for my (apparently different) IEEE tran style document.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid, you will have to come up with a MWE. In theory that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will have to close the question for now until I find an MWE.

Comment: @moewe: I deleted all the lines and packages in my real text on overleaf until I had a MWE which reproducibly failed to generate glossaries. When I pasted it into a fresh  & empty project on overleaf, it works just fine and generates glossaries though. Even deleting the caches does not do the trick for me.

Comment: what about `\printglossaries` ?

Comment: also does not work

Comment: Maybe it's a version issue. New projects on Overleaf use a new TeX live distribution. If you started your other project a while ago it may be using an older version of TeX live. I think Overleaf recently added an option to switch between distribution versions in  the menu. Try playing around with the versions to see what happens.

Comment: I created it only recently ( about 2 weeks ago). And inee, I use the lastest 2019 distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The support of overleaf told me that it should work as desired, but if and only if my tex document resides in the root folder - and not in sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

try using `\printglossaries` (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries)

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Comment: OP already has this command.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster suggested, this is due to the main file not sitting in the root folder. I added a `.latexmkrc` file in the root folder as a workaround for me. With this file, I can still keep my files organized in subfolders and the glossaries are rendered correctly. Please adapt according to your needs.

*Disclaimer: I am not an expert, but this works for me.*

```
# Specify the main files
@default_files = ('paper.tex');

$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %S';

# Specify the bibliography
$bibtex = 'bibtex %O %B';
$makeglossaries = 'makeglossaries %O %B';

# Continuous preview mode
$continuous_mode = 1;

# Output to PDF
$pdf_mode = 1;

# Keep auxiliary files
$clean_ext = "";

add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";

sub makeglossaries {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    my @args = ( "-q", "-d", $path, $base_name );
    if ($silent) { unshift @args, "-q"; }
    return system "makeglossaries", "-d", $path, $base_name; 
}

# Silence warnings
$silent = 1;
```