# \printglossary only works on lowest file level

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Hello I am trying to print glossaries with this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}
Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \gls{gcd}, which is abbreviated \gls{gcd}. This process 
is similar to that used for the \gls{lcm}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

This works fine. But once I move the file into another folder and recompile it from scratch using this file as the main file (on Overleaf) it doesn't work anymore. The acronyms still appear correctly in the text but the glossary doesn't get printed any longer. What am I missing here?

Before moving the file:
[image: Before moving]

After moving the file:
[image: After moving]

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of the Overleaf compiler https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542163/106162

Comment: That explains it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Dai Bowen this is most likeyl a limitation of Overleaf ([overleaf not printing glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541983/overleaf-not-printing-glossaries/542163#542163))